# vb.net i can't choose pdf files

Tags: vb.net, pdf, openfiledialog

in vb.net, i create a simple method where i choose and see a (pdf and image files) , i used fileopendialog
this is my code

```
Private Sub btn_parcour_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_parcour.Click
    fichier.Filter = "PDF Files |* .pdf "
    If fichier.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        fichier_txt.Text = fichier.FileName
    End If
End Sub
```

but when i open file dialog for To choose the file , i can't do it because , the message is you don't have a file

this is a screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR9JA.png)

Comment: Remove the space after the asterisk.

Comment: the same result

Comment: and the space after the asterisk and before the pipe symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many spaces in the filter. It will throw off the pattern matching.

```
'Remove all the extra spaces
fichier.Filter = "PDF Files|*.pdf"
```

For example if doing pdf and all other files

```
'Note no stray spaces where they are not needed
fichier.Filter = "PDF Files|*.pdf|All files(*.*)|*.*"
```